# Array multiple points in google maps with sql & php?

Tags: php, sql, google-maps

I a newbie in PHP. The code above works fine, but only with one marker. If I use top 1 to search one point it's ok.

When I change the top nubmer like 10 still shows one or last marker. How can I show multiple markers? 
I don't want to use json.
I think there's something like var array. 
Thank you

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css.css">
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; color: white }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=
          <?php echo $apikey; ?>&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        <?php
    $con =  mssql_connect(DB_HOST2, DB_USER2, DB_PASS2,DB_NAME2)
    or die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQ');
    mssql_select_db("MDTcan", $con);
    $query = ("select top 10 Cabno, lat, long, ttime
        from gps_history
        where ttime = (select min(ttime) from gps_history as f where f.Cabno = gps_history.Cabno)
        order by cabno"); 
    
 
    

    $result = mssql_query($query);

       while($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    
     echo ' var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(  
           '. $row['lat'].', '.$row['long'].'),
        zoom: 13
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
       mapOptions);
       var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng('.
           $row['lat'].', '.$row['long'].'); 
           
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
        position: myLatlng1, 
        map: map, 
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title:"'.$row['Cabno'].','.$row['Hora'].'"
         });';
        }
   ?>
       }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <center>
 </center>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only create the map once (currently you are creating a new map with one marker on it for each row in your database, when the query ends, the last one remains):

```
function initialize() {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  // initialize the map
  var mapOptions = {
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
         zoom: 13
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                        mapOptions);

<?php

... then add markers to it

  $result = mssql_query($query);

  while($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result))
  {  
    echo 'var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng('.$row['lat'].', '.$row['long'].');                                  
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
                            position: myLatlng1, 
                            map: map, 
                            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                            title:"'.$row['Cabno'].','.$row['Hora'].'"
                          });
     bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());';
   }
 ?>
   // center and zoom the map to show all the markers.
   map.fitBounds(bounds);
 }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Thank you all! the answer of @geocodezip works for me! I only create the map once... I was creating one map for one marker, RESOLVED! thanks you save my weekend!

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure your SQL request return several results?
2. Put it before your loop:

   var mapOptions = {
                             center: new google.maps.LatLng(
                                         '. $row['lat'].', '.$row['long'].'),
                             zoom: 13
                           };
                           var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                               mapOptions);
                               var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng('.
                                         $row['lat'].', '.$row['long'].');

There is perhaps some other mistakes. You could find it useful: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-latlng-literal

Comment: And create the map after your SQL request if you want to have access to your locations to center the map on.

Comment: Thank you Tom A, @geocodezip got what I was looking for!