# How can I show the icon in the marker of GeoJSON feature 'point' using google maps api?

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, geojson, marker

I'm trying to create a little app using the Google Maps JS API. I'm using the data layer to load a bunch of points from a GeoJSON file.

The file seems to be loading properly, and the map is displaying, but the icons that are set in `map.data.setstyle()` won't show.

```
function init() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 17,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.042248, -80.662319),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
        var theaterName = feature.getProperty('name');
        return {
            icon: {
                url: "maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/marina.png",
            }
            visible: true,
            clickable: true,
            title: theaterName
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Sara, welcome to StackOverflow. When asking questions please make sure to post the relevant code. Go ahead and hit that Edit button and put some code in there if you'd like some help.

Comment: function init(){
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
    zoom: 17,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.042248, -80.662319),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   });
   map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
  var theaterName = feature.getProperty('name');
  return {
    icon: {url:"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/marina.png",}
    visible: true,
    clickable: true,
    title: theaterName
  };
});
  }

Comment: Check This 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480105/how-to-show-multiple-areas-by-location-in-google-maps-using-php
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29572777/array-multiple-points-in-google-maps-with-sql-php

Comment: @sara - I meant the edit button under your question. Please refreain from posting code blocks in the copmments.

Comment: Have you added 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA7IZt-36CgqSGDFK8pChUdQXFyKIhpMBY&sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

You've got an extra semi-colon going on here:

```
url: "maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/marina.png";,
```

should be:

```
url: "maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/marina.png",
```

EDIT::

Ok, try this instead.

```
function init() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 17,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.042248, -80.662319),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(35.042248, -80.662319),
        map: map,
        title: "Some Title",
        icon: "maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/marina.png"
    });
}
```

Comment: Very Deep Observation.

Comment: please give example of the code geojson google maps api with some icon if you can!!!

Comment: @sara
1)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480105/how-to-show-multiple-areas-by-location-in-google-maps-using-php

2)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29572777/array-multiple-points-in-google-maps-with-sql-php

Comment: this examples is for the points but i am asking you for the feature in geojson :(

Comment: @sara - Ok, look at my edited answer. Please hit the checkmark by my answer to mark it, and if it helped, hit the up arrow to give me a vote too :)

Comment: my code is in the second answer can you help me to show the icon   "maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/marina.png"

Comment: @sara I edited my answer and gave you code to do that.

Comment: Adelphia @ yes but the function can't show the icon!!!! you can try it with my code :/

Comment: @Danish Enam i am doing it but it can show the icons!?